# fastest way to sort a key/value list in java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I got the following situation:

I have a list of unsorted keys and a different list of String terms. Both are connected in a way, meaning it looks kinda like this:

```
1 contents
5 term
2 queue
etc.
```

This list now contains 1000+ entries and I want to find a fast way to sort these two lists in descending order but of course I need the persistent connection to the strings.

```
5 term
2 queue
1 contents
```

I thought about putting the keys and values in a TreeMap, but the thing is, there can be duplicate keys, and I want to preserve them. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that holds the pair of values.

Make it extend `Comparable`.

Implement `compareTo()` so it orders by the number.

Use any of the sorting methods already in the API (Arrays.sort, or a `SortedSet`).

Have fun.

Comment: Using this approach PogoMips can simply use a List, correct, no need for the TreeMap?

Comment: @mikey Yes, no need of a Map. The pairs are kept together because you only deal with the object that encapsulates them.

Comment: hmm.. so it works but I'm not really convinced. It takes about 7 seconds to create 1,000 objects and put them in a list. And I'm going to have lists with 10,000+ entries.. are there any other options?

Comment: If you know the dimensions *a priori*, an array should be faster than the usual list. `ArrayList` has a constructor that accepts an initial capacity too. Other than that, improvements start being more complicated and suited for particular scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TreeMap` with `IntegerComparator` implemented like the following:

```
class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
   public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
        return two - one;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not if there are duplicate "keys" (or sorting indexes).

Comment: @jarnbjo, duplicate keys only requires that in the map, instead of storing `<Integer, String>` you store `<Integer, List<String>>`